# jquery not reading data attribute on subsequent click after setting attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a project where I'm trying to allow users to favorite a listing. I am trying to use a button and jquery to accomplish this.

I have the button setup as follows:

```
<button type="submit" name="fav" id="fav" data-action="add" data-listing-id="40" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-star-o pull-left notfav"></i> Add to Favorites</button>
```

When they click on the button I want to use AJAX to call a php script and pass it the listing ID and the action. Then it processes the favorite request and then returns success or fail. then if it was successful I want to change the action attribute to "delete" (if I just added it as a favorite) and change the HTML to show "My favorite" -- so they know the favorite was recorded.

Here is the JS I have currently:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#fav").click(function(){
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    var id = $(this).data("listing-id");
    var dataString = 'id='+id+'&action='+action;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/favsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            if(result=="login"){
                window.location.href = "/user_login.php";
            }else if(result=="success"){
                if(action=="add"){
                    $("#fav").html('<i class="fa fa-star pull-left fav"></i> My Favorite').button("refresh");
                    $("#fav").attr("data-action","delete");
                }else if(action=="delete"){
                    $("#fav").html('<i class="fa fa-star-o pull-left notfav"></i> Add to Favorites').button("refresh");
                    $("#fav").attr("data-action","add");
                }
            } else if (result=="fail"){
                console.log(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

});

Now...The issue is the above HTML and JS works on the first click. But then on subsequent clicks its not picking up the changed data-action value. So if it wasn't a favorite and I click the button, it changes it to "My favorite" and the action to "delete" but when I click the button again, it tries to add the favorite again. it doesnt see the new action value of delete?

Can anyone spot my issue??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to read the data with `.data` you should also set it with `.data`:

```
$("#fav").data("action","delete");
```

jQuery's data doesn't use the data attribute to store the data when you set it, it actually stores it in some form of js object.  It will read the initial value from the attribute but then moves to the object.

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).